# Creating a time series in ElasticSearch based on date field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm begginer in Elasticsearch and I want to create time series analysis for my index based on date field (not based on system time). can anyone help me? my index mapping is like this:

```
{"test" : {
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "createdat" : {"type" : "date"},
       "age"    : {"type" : "integer"}     
 }}}}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: i create index pattern `test*` and use `visual builder` in kibana. i want to have timeline  base on `createdat` field for  `aggregations` of `age` field.